# Grails indexed parameters

Tags: grails, properties, indexed

I have a list of `Team` objects that have an `Integer seed` property. I want to edit all the teams' seeds at once, in a single form. I'm *sure* that Grails supports indexed parameters, but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I have, and it works but I'm jumping through *way* too many hoops and there's got to be a better way.

gsp:

```
<g:form action="setSeeds">
...
  <g:each in="${teams}" status="i" var="team">
    <input type="hidden" name="teams[${i}].id" value="${team.id}">
    <input type="text" size="2" name="teams[${i}].seed" value="${team.seed}">
  </g:each>
</g:form>
```

controller:

```
def setSeeds = {
  (0..<30).each { i ->
    def team = Team.get(Integer.parseInt(params["teams[${i}].id"]))
    team.seed = Integer.parseInt(params["teams[${i}].seed"])
  }
  redirect(action:list)
}
```

Isn't that awful? Way too much noise. How can I do something along the lines of:

```
params.teams.each { t ->
  def team = Team.get(t.id)
  team.seed = t.seed
}
```

That is, how do I map params named `team[0].seed`, `team[0].id`, `team[1].seed`, `team[1].id` to a List?

In [Stripes](http://www.stripesbook.com) you can just have a `List<Team>` property and it will just work. I expect no less from Grails! ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this without any shenanigans.

Forget about the hidden parameter and just use the team ID in the seed parameter. In the GSP:

```
<g:form action="setSeeds"> 
... 
  <g:each in="${teams}" var="team"> 
    <input type="text" size="2" name="teams.seeds.${team.id}"
      value="${team.seed}"> 
  </g:each> 
</g:form>
```

Then, in the controller:

```
params.teams.seeds.each { teamId, seed ->
  def team = Team.get(teamId.toInteger())
  team.seed = seed.toInteger()
  team.save()
}
redirect(action:list)
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

`params` is more than a regular Map, it's a `GrailsParameterMap` that automatically builds up sub-Map structures based on splitting the parameter names by '.'. You might take advantage of this by using the following gsp:

```
<g:form action="seed">
 <g:each in="${teams}" status="i" var="team">
   <input type="hidden" name="teams.${i}.id" value="${team.id}">
   <input type="text" size="2" name="teams.${i}.seed" value="${team.seed}">
  </g:each>
 <g:submitButton name="update" value="Update" />
</g:form>
```

NB: there's no [] in the name attributes. The controller is now pretty simple using some black Grails magic :

```
log.error "params = ${params}"
params.teams.findAll {k,v -> !k.contains(".")}.each { k,v ->
       bindData(Team.get(v.id), v)
}
```

The first operation `findAll` filters out all parameters with a dot inside. The rest is a map of maps holding the row id in `k` and the `id` and `seed` in `v`.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone else is having troubles getting this to work. Using grails 1.3.4, instead of getting the expected sub-map I get what looks like a string representation of the sub-map. E.g, params.toString() "[filters.1.value:123, filters:["1":["value":"123"], "1.value":"123"], action:list, controller:user]"

Comment: Yeah, I'm having all kinds of trouble with this in 2015. Seems grails now returns all parameter values as strings, which renders the 'maplist' string practically useless as bcowdery found years ago.

Answer (score 1):

In 2015....
Grails works a little differently now and you may find yourself running into strings rather than the expected sub-maps.I got something to work by doing
something like..

```
params.nested.each{
               if(!it.getKey().contains('.')){
                 //to get a map rather than a string...    
                  params.nested[it.getKey()];
               }
           };
```

**EDIT: By The Way...**

inputs that have the same name, like

```
  <input name="item.choice" type="checkbox" value="3" />
  < input name="item.choice" type="checkbox" value="4"/>
```

Are put into a List IF more then one are submitted. So if both of the above were checked

```
   <input name="item.choice" type="checkbox" value="3" checked />
   < input name="item.choice" type="checkbox" value="4" checked/>
```

You would get a list.

But if only one is checked you do NOT get a List(at least in grails verison I use), you get a single value.

```
     <input name="item.choice" type="checkbox" value="3" checked />
     < input name="item.choice" type="checkbox" value="4" />
```

That means in a controller, if I were to do something like

```
  params['item.choice'].each{
          def item=Item.get(it)
  }
```

It would throw an error if only one item was submitted. One groovy way to get around this is

```
 ([]+(params['item.choice']?:[])).each{
         def item=Item.get(it)
 }
```

If the parameter is set and not a list, it puts the value into the empty list; If the parameter is set and a list, the plus operator will add all the individual values to the empty list; if the parameter is not set, it will add two empty lists together, which creates a single empty list.

Comment: Any idea why this is the case? Why are nested sub-maps broken?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps but you could use a closure with it like:

```
<g:each in="${teams}">
     <p>id: ${it.id}</p>
     <p>seed: ${it.seed}</p>
</g:each>
```

You could probably build a list from this instaed of outputting html. or build your form with it.

Comment: I'm already using a closure to build a form. The question is, how do I retrieve the indexed parameters in the controller to build a list?