# access to input value which has array form name attribute

Tags: grails

I have inputtext filed in my gsp llike this :

```
<tr class="context">
    <td width="5%" ><a class="addButton" href="#" style="display:none;"  >+</a></td>
    <td width="60%"><input type="text" name="iwd0_description" value="" id="iwd0_description" /></td>                   
    <td width="10%"><input type="text" name="iwd0_tax" value="" id="iwd0_tax" /></td>
    <td width="10%"><input type="text" name="iwd0_discount" value="" id="iwd0_discount" /></td>
    <td width="10%"><input type="null" name="iwd0_total" value="0" required="" id="iwd0_total" /></td>
    <td width="5%" ><a class="deleteButton" href="#"  style="display:none;" >-</a></td>
</tr>

<tr class="context">
    <td width="5%" ><a class="addButton" href="#"     style="display:none;"  >+</a></td>
    <td width="60%"><input type="text" name="iwd1_description" value="" id="iwd1_description" /></td>                   
    <td width="10%"><input type="text" name="iwd1_tax" value="" id="iwd1_tax" /></td>
    <td width="10%"><input type="text" name="iwd1_discount" value="" id="iwd1_discount" /></td>
    <td width="10%"><input type="null" name="iwd1_total" value="0" required="" id="iwd1_total" /></td>
    <td width="5%" ><a class="deleteButton" href="#"  style="display:none;" >-</a></td> 
</tr>
```

How can I access to input value in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Form values are sent over HTTP using request parameters (for GET requests), with the `input` name attribute used to set the parameter "key". So your HTTP request will have the following params: `?iwd0_tax=userInput1&iwd0_discount=userInput2` etc.

Grails makes request parameters available by the `params` var in controllers:

```
def iwd0_tax = params.iwd0_tax
```

Grails can also populate a bean/class from the request params automatically. The bean is called a `command object`. See details in the [Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects).

Comment: thanks,but my question is how to get iwd0_tax iwd1_tax iwd2_tax as you see name attribute is an array format name I don't know how to iterate

Comment: `request params` can be sent as an array but the `name` attribute is usually the same for each element e.g. `iwd_tax=foo&iwd_tax=bar` - Grails can grab the List "version" with `params.list('iwd_tax')` but this won't work in your case as the array is implicit in the name, its not an actual array. So it come down to how you are creating your form inputs in the first place - it doesn't look very Grails-sy to me.

Comment: This post may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/19462901/249327 - you'll need t parse out the array from the params yourself I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
def i = 0
while (params."iwd${i}_tax") {          
    println 'tax'+"${i}" + params."iwd${i}_tax"                     
    i++
}
```